# Android: soft keyboard Backspace on EditText not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, soft-keyboard

This is what happens:
Activity A and B have an `EditText` and they both have `IME_SEARCH`. The input is done only via soft keyboard on a SAMSUNG tablet.
On Activity A I can use the `EditText` without problems. The thing is that on Activity B I can't erase text with backspace after I hit 'space' or whenever I use a word from the suggestions. It behaves like there wasn't text there anymore. If I type new characters, I can erase them up to the space.

Important points:

1. The View hierarchy that contains the `EditTexts` are identical
2. The code that configures the `IME_SEARCH` processing (via `setOnEditorActionListener`) is identical
3. The `TextWatcher` of both are also identical
4. In the Manifest, both activities are configures with

   > ```
   > android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|orientation"
   > android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustUnspecified"
   > ```

I set a breakpoint on the method `beforeTextChanged` of both `TextWatcher`. I inserted a 'space' and hit 'backspace'. On the `Edittext` of activity A, the method is triggered but on activity B's it is not triggered. I can't see the reason for this to happen since the properties of both `Edittext` are configured identically.
I also tried removing the `IME` option but the behavior kept the same.

Does anyone know what could be happening?

**EDIT 1:**

```
searchTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (s.length() == 0) {
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else{
                    btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

searchTxt.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    buildGrid();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**EDIT 2:**
The layout hierarchy is as following.

```
<LinearLayout
    ... >

    <include layout="@layout/title_bar" />
    <RelativeLayout
        ...>
        <EditText
            ...>
```

Comment: Can you share the text watcher?

Comment: @toshkinl Sure, I've just added it

Comment: Seems fine. "word from the suggestions" adds space at the end that's why you can't erase, not because it is from the suggestions. Are you sure there are no differences between the 2 layouts and Activities regarding the EditText?

Comment: @toshkinl I checked the layouts and in fact there was 2 differences. I copied the code from the working activity's layout to the not working one but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @toshkinl the "word from the suggestions" was just another case that caused the problem. the real deal is the space character that the use can insert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that, for some reason, the Activity B was overriding `dispatchKeyEvent()` and always returning `true`. Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems that you are facing and I somehow managed to stumble on the solution. Apparently, I had setOnKeyListener to 'return true'. After I changed it to 'return false', the phone keyboard works perfect with backspace functioning properly once again on edittext. Hope this helps:

```
.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  ...
  return false;
                }
        });
```